# C# - Convert JBIG1 images to other image formats

Tags: c#, .net

I need to convert a JBIG1 image to another image format, such as JPEG or PNG, but I can't seem to find anything related to this.

This JBIG1 image is received encoded in Base64.

I've tried using System.Drawing in .NET to accomplish this, but a "System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid" exception is thrown on calling Image.FromStream() using the JBIG1 byte array data.

See code below:

```
byte[] binData = ConvertFromBase64StringToArray("BASE64 ENCODED JBIG1 IMAGE GOES HERE");
Image img = binData.ConvertToImage();
img.Save("C:/Images/converted-from-jbig.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Functions used:

```
public static byte[] ConvertFromBase64StringToArray(string base64String)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length))
    {
        data = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return data;
}

public static Image ConvertToImage(this byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms); //exception thrown in this line 
    return returnImage;
}
```

Does anyone have any knowledge to share about this topic?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a third party library to work with JBig files. It looks like https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET has support for that.

Comment: I have installed the Image Magick package, but when trying to read an .jbg image I get the following exception: 

ImageMagick.MagickMissingDelegateErrorException: 'no decode delegate for this image format `JBG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.

I've read on https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php that JBIG requires the jbigkit-1.6.tar.gz C library, but I have no idea on how to link this with .NET